# Magento 2 login account getting error: No linked stock found

Tags: magento2, data-migration

When I login to account. The server redirect to /customer/account/index/ and getting this error:

[image]

The main domain on our multi-site.

I upgraded from Magento 1.9.4 to 2.3

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't find an answer or anyone else looking for an answer - go to the admin panel and then Stores - Inventory - Stocks. Add a new stock or resave in case you have one.